# ?90's ghost short-story anthology book jacket illustration

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, anthology-book

I'm looking for a children's short story antholgy about ghosts. I remember one illustration in the book had a jacket hanging in a closet, maybe a raincoat. The ghost in this particular short story was a kid. I'm not sure how he died, but it was possibly because he didn't wear the jacket? Possibly someone gave him the jacket when they noticed him outside? Afterwards he was able to move on, but I think that the person who gave him the jacket notice that it was still in the closet, or it was somehow later returned? Thanks in advance for any help with this. :)